# cordova platform ios does not take into account confi.xml preferences

Tags: ios, cordova, preferences

I am trying to build a cordova app. Actually to update my cordova app.
Somehow ( I think it happened after building via the CLI instead of XCODE) it stopped taking into account preferences in config.xml.

I checked both files the one in parent and the copy inside ios platform and are the same.
I did not change anycode at all, last change was adding the GADIdentifier in the plist.

How do I know it is not read/ taken into account?
Splashscreen does not go away -> 
When it was working like some hours ago that I started debugging.

I did all the usual that a noob is doing like removing everythin re-installing, clean build etc.
But still the problem remains.

Any ideas???

Thank you in advance

Comment: conffig.xml typo in the title

Answer (score 0):

Go to your  deviceready event handler and add

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

By default, the js file that has the deviceready handler is at
www/js/index.js

Comment: it might work for the splashscreen, I will try but that does not resolve the fact that config.xml is not being taken into account